# Is there a way to select an element that is not an option from a dropdown by text using selenium and C#

Tags: c#, selenium, select, text

Something like this code:

```
    public void SideMenuNavigateTo(string menuOption)
    {
       this.SideMenu.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(text(),'" + menuOption "')]"));
    }
```

This code doesn't work, but is there a way to do something similar?

Comment: It should work what's the error ?

Comment: The Xpath fails with "CS1501 No overload for method 'XPath' takes 2 arguments" and the string is marked in red because of syntax errors. But if you look at it you will see that there are no syntax errors...

Comment: Is there a syntax error further up in the file, maybe? Sometimes syntax errors cause a cascade of issues down the file.

Comment: Sometimes it's also worth closing Visual Studio and deleting the `.vs` folder in the root of the solution. That contains a bunch of temp files that sometimes get a little wonky.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my problem. The syntax should be a bit different

this.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath(String.Format("//a[contains(text(), '{0}')]", menuOption)));